# Manhwa where the MC cannot return to his world even after defeating the demon king many times and summons a hero on his own as he is in a loop

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I don't remember but it is a manga/manhwa where the main character (MC) is transported to another world but cannot go back to his world after defeating the demon king and is stuck in a loop, so he tries all the things but at the end, he summons another hero to break the loop. And turns the demon king into a female by sacrificing the demon king's daughter.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely *[Newbie Management](https://anilist.co/manga/151615/Newbie-Management/)*.

> "Only the true hero can take down the Demon Lord." Well, Presidio Cage has already accomplished that... numerous times. He can catch the Demon Lord with his bare hands, but every time he does, **he's sent to the beginning of the game again**. Although he knows all the tips and tricks, he doesn't know how to escape this endless loop. In order to switch things up, **Cage summons a "new" hero to defeat the enemy** in his stead. Now, he's ready to create the ultimate newbie and finally get back home!

The synopsis is a perfect match for the question.

I can't find the detail of sacrificing the demon lord's daughter in the chapters I checked, but he does confirm that he has a daughter in the first chapter.

[image]